# Not hitting breakpoints debugging Android Junit tests in Eclipse

Tags: android, debugging, junit

Getting an error running a Android unit test which extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, and so want try and debug the test. However the break points are being ignored and when debug as Android Junit Test it gets to Running tests...

Here's the console log:

```
[2011-03-16 17:02:54 - AppName] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device [my device ID here]
[2011-03-16 17:02:55 - AppName] Collecting test information
[2011-03-16 17:02:55 - AppName] Test run failed: Process crashed.
[2011-03-16 17:02:55 - AppName] Test run finished
[2011-03-16 17:02:56 - AppName] Sending test information to Eclipse
[2011-03-16 17:02:56 - AppName] Running tests...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the debugger is attaching to the process?  Are you sure the breakpoints are being accepted by Eclipse?  (They change from a bullet icon to a bullet-overlaid-with-a-checkmark icon when Eclipse sends them to the VM.)

Comment: I am seeing this problem as well. How did the answer below help?

Comment: @RobertKarl something wasn't getting initialised correctly and so the debugger never connected. But tbh i'm struggling to remember how i fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
[2011-03-15 22:46:12 - TemperatureConverterTest] Collecting test information
[2011-03-15 22:46:13 - TemperatureConverterTest] Sending test information to Eclipse
[2011-03-15 22:46:13 - TemperatureConverterTest] Running tests...
**[2011-03-15 22:46:14 - TemperatureConverterTest] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.example.aatg.tc' on port 8654**
[2011-03-15 22:46:31 - TemperatureConverterTest] Test run finished
```

Notice that your test is crashing even before getting the debugger connected.
There might be a problem in you constructor.

Comment: Indeed that is the case.  The constructor is not debuggable, so any breakpoints you set in it will not stop.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the application you are testing has defined android:debuggable="true".

If your application is not debuggable, running the tests in debug mode does not work. E.g. you will not hit any breakpoints and you get the error message in the log as mentioned above.