# Not able to debug Android Instrumentation tests on Device from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

For the first time i am trying to debug an instrumentation test from eclipse over my connected android nexus 4 device. The tests are running fine over my device but i am not able to debug the tests with it. Breakpoints are not hit

I have enabled everything :
Device is connected with usb debugging
My application has the android debuggable attribute set as true.

i tried to find answer to this question. But did not find any proper one including this [Not hitting breakpoints debugging Android Junit tests in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329063/not-hitting-breakpoints-debugging-android-junit-tests-in-eclipse)

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

My silly mistake.

I had a problem with my app in the code against which i was debugging.